# The employee, who was a new hire, was let go later that evening

Tags: meaning

> "The employee, who was a new hire, was let go later that evening"

What does it mean?
Does it mean "fired" ?

Comment: “let go” is sometimes a euphemism for “fired”  sometimes it means “terminated” without meaning “fired” in all cases it means the guy doesn’t work there anymore.

Comment: *[let go](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/let-someone-go): (informal) to officially tell someone that they can no longer work at a job* – Macmillan

Comment: You need to look at the context. The relationship between *employee* and *let go* does suggest *fired*, particularly with *new hire* thrown in. But if the context was a hostage situation, *let go* could mean *released*.

Comment: @Lawrence - very good point.  That almost seems more likely to me now that you mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "let go" is an idiomatic expression and also an euphemism for the harsher word "fired."

Comment: Worth noting that 'let go' is an American idiom.  It is rarely heard in British English, where 'fired' is the norm.

Comment: Double-worth noting that "let go" in the US typically connotes being *laid off* (due to financial troubles, strategic reorganizations, M&A activity, etc), as opposed to *fired* (i.e. being singled out as an individual and terminated for cause, e.g. chronic productivity issues, interpersonal issues, safety issues, and so on.)